# how to overwrite the inherited property values of derived class with that of base class instance

Tags: c#, .net

I have a **Human** class with simple two properties *Age* and *Name*. Then, I have another class **Woman** derived from the **Human** class and it has one extra properties *FavCream*. Now, I have two different instances of these classes say **h1**(of base class **Human**) and **w1** (of derived class **Woman**) and I simply want to overwrite all the derived properties of **w1** with the corresponding values from **h1**.

However, I did not found this built-in. I do not like to create a public method on Woman class which manually does the assignment job. I think, I can create a utility function using reflection feature but looking for proven way to deal with this.

Is this impossible? Can not we have any advantage of inheritance in this scenario? or Is this illogical?

Please have patience with me. Thanks!

```
class Program
    {
        private static Woman _aWoman;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var aHuman = new Human() { Age = 25, Name = "Ram" };
            Program._aWoman = new Woman() { Age = 22, FavCream = "Ponds" , Name = "Sita"};
            Console.WriteLine("Woman is " + Program._aWoman.ToString()); // prints Age = 22 Name = Sita FavCream = Ponds
            Console.WriteLine("Human is " + aHuman.ToString()); // prints Age = 25 Name = Ram

            **// Do something here so woman derived property has auto over written with property of human instance.**

            Console.WriteLine("after overwriting, woman is " + _aWoman.ToString());
            // The result I m looking for here is  "Age = 25 Name = Ram FavCream = Ponds"
        }
    }

    internal class Human
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Age = " + this.Age + " Name = " + this.Name;
        }
    }

    internal class Woman: Human
    {
        public string FavCream { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return base.ToString() + " FavCream = " + this.FavCream;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:** 
I ended on creating a method and copied the base class properties using reflection. Also, I tried to enhance this with generic restriction but not succeeded yet.

Thanks everyone for such quick reply.

```
// Trying to make it generic... but could not enforce contraint that T must be base class of 'this'
        public void Overwrite<T>(T baseInstance) where T : Human 
        {
            Type baseType = baseInstance.GetType();
            Type derivedType = this.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] propInfos = null;

            propInfos = baseType.GetProperties();

            foreach (PropertyInfo eachProp in propInfos)
            {
                PropertyInfo baseProp = (baseType).GetProperty(eachProp.Name);
                object baseVal = baseProp.GetValue(baseInstance, null);
                eachProp.SetValue(this, baseVal, null);
            }
        }
```

Comment: what if you have got two instances of Human h1 and h2? from where you want w1 to get properties from ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it using reflection
 To fetch all the properties on Human

```
// get all public static properties of MyClass type
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
propertyInfos = typeof(Human).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                              BindingFlags.Static);
```

You can use PropertyInfo GetValue() and SetValue() Methods for getting from Human and Setting it to Woman. 
Look at MSDN : SetValue : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axt1ctd9.aspx
GetValue : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx

Instead of assigning values at runtime, I would suggest you overload implicit or explicit operator and simply do a casting from Human to Woman.

```
Woman newWoman = (Woman)H1;
```

All the logic for converting Human to Woman would be dumped in the overrloaded method.

Answer (score 0):

The Human class instance that you create is totally separate to the Woman class instance.
It's difficult to see what you're trying to achieve, perhaps this?

```
w1.Age = h1.Age;
w1.Name = h1.Name;
```

Comment: Yes, but automatically. So, it is reusable across different type of classes.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is illogical. Even if you had two instances of Woman, w1 and w2, there is no builtin mechanism for copying all of the properties from w1 to w2.

You will need to implement this using reflection, but that is a fairly straightforward operation.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from other answers you can simply write some function in `Human` class which will copy properties you're interested in:

```
class Human
{
    ...

    public void CopyFrom(Human h)
    {
        this.Age = g.Age;
        this.Name = g.Name;
    }
}
```

Other solution can be using `automapper`